# Does a yield need to return a value. Bluebird Promise.coroutine

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, coroutine

I've read through the docs on http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html but I feel i'm misunderstand how I should be `yield`ing functions.

I'm getting a `Unhandled rejection TypeError: A value undefined was yielded that could not be treated as a promise`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpeVeP?editors=0012

Based on some of the examples in the docs, I should be able to create a `Promise.coroutine` and then `yield` multiple functions.

```
const someOthFunc = id => {
  console.log(id, 'im in here');
};

const test = Promise.coroutine(function*(id) {
  console.log(id, '<<');
  yield someOthFunc(id);
});

test('123');
```

If I yield a function, does that other function need to be a coroutine also?

Comment: Your function is synchronous. So why are you using promises (and bluebird, and coroutines) at all here?

Comment: And no, you should not be yielding functions. You should yield promises.

Comment: @Bergi Just creating an example so i can understand how it works etc. So what should my return statement be, say within the `someOthFunc` I finished what I'm doing, would i return a new promise?

Comment: No. I'm saying that you should be using all this stuff only when doing asynchronous things. (And yes, if `someOthFunc` does something asynchronous, *then* it should return a promise)

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't need to be a coroutine. Your function `someOthFunc` need to return a value by the way.